# how append new entry in different session

Tags: php

the problem I am experimenting is about this code:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    /* ... */

    if(!array_key_exists('entries', $_SESSION) || array_key_exists('reset', $_GET))
    {
        $_SESSION['entries'] = array();
    }

    $_SESSION['entries'][] = array("name" => $_GET["name"]);

    // json
    $json_string = json_encode($_SESSION['entries']);

    //file
    $newfile="location.json";
    $file = fopen ($newfile, "w");
    fwrite($file, $json_string);
    fclose ($file);
    ?>
```

The script get te POST variables, encode them in json format and save to a file, appending new  entries to the file.
It works well, but when I start a new session, the file is overwrited, and start again from empty.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

change the mode

```
 $file = fopen ($newfile, "a");
```

> **'a'**    Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
>   file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

[`Reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

#### Alternative :

use [`file_put_contents`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)  with **FILE_APPEND**  AND **LOCK_EX** flag

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.

```
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at same time
file_put_contents($file, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: You are right but this solution seems not good for me because it appends to file all the fike twice with the + new entry.